# How do I return the right error for this rustlings question (errors5)?

Tags: rust

I am looking at rustlings' errors5.rs which we have to catch errors and change the code to reflect the correctly returned `Result`. I cannot figure it out even with the help of hints, here is my code but it still cannot get past the error.

My code:

```
// errors5.rs

// This program uses a completed version of the code from errors4.
// It won't compile right now! Why?
// Execute `rustlings hint errors5` for hints!
 
// I AM NOT DONE

use std::error;
use std::fmt;
use std::num::ParseIntError;

// TODO: update the return type of `main()` to make this compile.
fn main() -> Result<(), ParseIntError> {
    let pretend_user_input = "42";
    let x: i64 = pretend_user_input.parse().unwrap()?;
    // let x: i64 = match pretend_user_input.parse()? {
//      Ok(()) => x,
//      ParseIntError(x) => Err(x),
  //   }
    match println!("output={:?}", PositiveNonzeroInteger::new(x)?) {
        () => return Ok(()),
        ParseIntError => return Err(x),
    }
    // Ok(())
}
```

The error still is:

```
⚠️  Compilation of exercises/error_handling/errors5.rs failed!, Compiler error message:

error[E0425]: cannot find value `e` in this scope
  --> exercises/error_handling/errors5.rs:23:30
   |
23 |     ParseIntError => return Err(e),
   |                                 ^ help: a local variable with a similar name exists: `x`

error[E0277]: `?` couldn't convert the error to `ParseIntError`
  --> exercises/error_handling/errors5.rs:21:65
   |
14 | fn main() -> Result<(), ParseIntError> {
   |              ------------------------- expected `ParseIntError` because of this
...
21 |     match println!("output={:?}", PositiveNonzeroInteger::new(x)?) {
   |                                                                 ^ the trait `From<CreationError>` is not implemented for `ParseIntError`
   |
   = note: the question mark operation (`?`) implicitly performs a conversion on the error value using the `From` trait
   = note: required by `from`

error: aborting due to 2 previous errors
```

Some help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you're only supposed to update the return type of `main()` in this exercise. You can try `main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>>` which is a sort of catch-all for all error types that implement `Error`. You'll need also: `use std::error::Error;`

Answer (score 2):

Here's what my main looks like:

```
type MainResult<T> = std::result::Result<T, Box<dyn error::Error>>;
// TODO: update the return type of `main()` to make this compile.
fn main() -> MainResult<()> {
    let pretend_user_input = "42";
    let x: i64 = pretend_user_input.parse()?;
    println!("output={:?}", PositiveNonzeroInteger::new(x)?);
    Ok(())
}
```

Box allows conversion of any type that implements the Error trait into a Box trait object that conserves the underlying type, its drawback being that the underlying type can only be known at runtime.

[documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/rust-by-example/error/multiple_error_types/boxing_errors.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
fn main() -> Result<(), ParseIntError> {
    let pretend_user_input = "42";
    let x: i64 = pretend_user_input.parse()?;
    println!("output={:?}", PositiveNonzeroInteger::new(x));
    Ok(())
}
```

it works

Comment: This is not expected, the code says: `// TODO: update the return type of `main()` to make this compile.`

Comment: your line starting `printlin!` is not the correct line from the question.